# Why can't I boot a Windows 10 ISO from a Seagate Backup Plus Slim USB storage device?

Tags: windows-10, boot, usb, linux-mint

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad that was running Mint Linux using full-disk encryption.  I downloaded the Windows 10 ISO from Microsoft and used whatever Mint uses to create bootable USB devices to put the Windows 10 ISO on a Seagate Backup Plus Slim.  I tried to boot from USB using the Lenovo boot menu but the computer went to the same Mint disk encryption log-in screen as usual.  Inside Mint, I deleted the partitions on the hard drive and rebooted.  Now when I boot it goes to the Grub rescue command prompt.

I'm guessing that either the tool I used in Mint to create a bootable USB device didn't do the trick.  Or maybe the Windows 10 ISO isn't bootable unless you use Microsoft's media creation tool itself??  If that's the case, then how can I make a bootable Windows 10 USB device without using Windows in the first place??  :-)

Comment: _"Or maybe the Windows 10 ISO isn't bootable unless you use Microsoft's media creation tool itself?"_ - yes, most ISOs aren't. _"how can I make a bootable Windows 10 USB device without using Windows in the first place?"_ - have you tried to google this?

Comment: I did, yes, and it looks like you do have to use a tool to make a bootable device using the Windows 10 ISO.  But I thought I did that from within Mint using whatever USB creation tool it ships with.  Either it failed to perform the job correctly or . . . something else I'm unaware of.  I presume it's not the fault of the USB device since BIOS seems to detect it just fine.

Comment: I'm going to try recreating bootable device using a different tool.

Comment: You have to use a tool designed specifically to support Windows ISOs, like WoeUSB.

Comment: "isn't bootable unless you use Microsoft's media creation tool itself??" - This simply isn't true.

Comment: "You have to use a tool designed specifically to support Windows ISOs, like WoeUSB."

Ugh!!  That stinks.  But I will check it out.  Since I have to.  :-)  ;-)

Comment: @gronostaj All Windows install ISOs are bootable, as in order for an ISO to be bootable, it has to be created that way _([`oscdimg`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/oscdimg-command-line-options) is used to generate the Windows install ISOs)_

Comment: @JW0914 They are bootable as optical media images, which is what ISO was intended for. But they are not bootable if interpreted as a raw disk image, ie. they don't have a proper MBR, GPT or ESP. Modern Linux ISOs are oftentimes [modified](https://wiki.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=Isohybrid) to be both a valid ISO and a valid disk image, so one can `dd` them directly to a flash drive and boot them without additional tools. Windows ISOs don't support that, which can lead to confusion for Linux folks.

Comment: Argh!  Well, I'm not having luck installing WoeUSB on my Ubuntu LTS system.  I added the repositories as directed and there still remain unsatisfied dependencies.  This is way more complicated than it needs to be, in my opinion.  :-)  I would have thought that M$ would make it easier in this era of Linux-friendliness to do a bare-metal Windows install, without first requiring a Windows system to be up and running.